# Сокет и события мыши

Tags: c#

Написал приложение - сокет с использованием формы - сворачиваю это приложение в область уведомлений. Как только клиент устанавливает соединений, показывается форма вместе с консольным окном - в нем отображается инфа о работе сокета. Вот в чем проблема - консольное окно нельзя свернуть или развернуть, пока сокет ждет обращения клиента, а когда обращение произошло и открылась форма, то консольное окно начинает прятаться по щелчку на иконке.

Как это можно решить? Т.е. как организовать возможность скрытия и открытия консольного окна в любой момент времени, а не только при обращении клиента?

вот пример сокета асинхронного (сервера) с консольным окном, которое не реагирует на клики по иконке tray. Почему - не ясно:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WIATest;

namespace AsyncSocketScan
{
    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        private static bool mWinVisible = false;
        private const int HIDE = 0;
        private const int SHOW = 1;
        private static System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenuTray;
        private static System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItemTray;
        private static System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
        private static IntPtr mThisConsole = GetConsoleWindow();
        // Thread signal.
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public AsynchronousSocketListener()
        {
        }

        public static void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // The DNS name of the computer
            // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                    allDone.Reset();

                    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);
                    
                    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            allDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;

            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                    state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    // All the data has been read from the 
                    // client. Display it on the console.
                    Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                        content.Length, content);
                    // Echo the data back to the client.
                    Send(handler, content);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not all data received. Get more.
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        public static void showWindowConsole(bool Yes)
        {
            mWinVisible = Yes;
            ShowWindow(mThisConsole, Yes ? SHOW : HIDE);
        }

        public static void trayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            showWindowConsole(!mWinVisible);
            //Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        }

        public static int Main(String[] args)
        {
            var tray = new NotifyIcon();
            tray.Text = "Сокет";
            tray.Icon = new Icon("img/scanner.ico");
            tray.BalloonTipText = "Сокет запущен";
            tray.Click += new EventHandler(trayClick);
            tray.Visible = true;
            tray.ShowBalloonTip(100000);
            showWindowConsole(true);
            StartListening();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Использую C#.

Comment: Та ладно? Что, правда что ли?

Comment: Удаление бесконечного цикла приводит к тому, что ожидается всего лишь 1 обращение клиента - после него прога завершается. Если убрать allDone.WaitOne(), то даже не происходит ожидания соединения - прога завершает работу. Добавление Application.Run() ничего не меняет. Вопрос открыт.

Comment: Ну надо убрать цикл и waitone, а в коллбеке соединения опять ставить асинхронное прослушивание. Application.Run() надо добавить что бы приложение получало сообщения и не выходило раньше времени.

Answer (score 4):

У вас работа с сетью в UI-потоке? Так лучше не делать, перенесите обращения к сокетам в BackgroundWorker'ы например.

**UPD:**

> Клиент и серверная часть у меня стоят локально - они будут стоять на одной машине и в дальнейшем.

Это не влияет на работу с сетью.

> Перенос в бэкграунд как осуществить и что это даст?

Если я вас правильно понял, то это даст именно то, что вам надо. При операциях с сокетом в режим ожидания будет переходить фоновый поток, а не UI. Ваш интерфейс при этом останется отзывчивым.

Сделать это можно по разному, поищите в интернете. Основная идея это инкапсулировать обращения к сокетам или весь алгоритм работы с сетью в отдельный поток.

Так же можно использовать асинхронные варианты методов accept, receive и т.д. При этом так же не будет блокироваться UI поток, а сообщения о завершении операций будут приходить в коллбеки.

По второму способу есть статьи [1](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/sampleprograms/article.php/c7695/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-I.htm) и [2](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c8781/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-II.htm), думаю он предпочтительней, хотя сам не пробовал =).

**UPD2:**

В примере есть бесконечнй цикл и прямое ожидание соединения. Поэтоу это все равно что обычный вызов =) Не знаю зачем такой пример. Возможно асинхронное программирование надо все равно в бекграунд поток (скорей всего оно сокращает их необходимое количество).

Для того что принимать сообщения нужно убрать бесконечный цикл и allDone.WaitOne(); Так же надо добавить Application.Run() после вызова StartListening(), что бы появился обаботчик сообщений. После этого окно скрывается и раскрывается.

Comment: Клиент и серверная часть у меня стоят локально - они будут стоять на одной машине и в дальнейшем. Перенос в бэкграунд как осуществить и что это даст? Бьюсь над задачей уже третий день... Когда серверная часть ждет запроса от клиента, то приложение просто не реагирует ни на какие события...

Comment: Брал простой пример асинхронного сокета... При ожидании запроса от клиента также нет реакции на события, а именно на попытку показать/спрятать консольное окно в трее. Если кто-то знает, как обойти блокировку проги при ожидании запроса клиента, киньте плиз пример - пусть самый примитивный, но показывающий путь обхода данной проблемы. Подобных примеров не мог найти сколько не искал

Comment: А можете свой пример выложить? Я посмотрю.

Comment: Сверху мой пример - асинхронный сокет скатал с мсдн, чтобы наверняка. Прикрутил к нему иконку в трее. Получаю хэндл консольного окна и при клике на иконку вызываю метод, чтобы показать/спрятать консольное окно. Если вместо StartListening() написать Application.Run(), окно реагирует на событие.

Comment: часть кода в начале не форматнулась, но, думаю, понять можно

Comment: а вы добавте там гден не форматнулось 4 пробела в начало =)

Comment: Еще раз обновил ответ